Positivity of self intersection of indeterminacy locus of meromorphic function
In the book "Holomorphic Vector Bundles over Compact Complex Surfaces" by Vasile Brînzănescu, in the proof of theorem 2.13 there is the following claim

Let $X$ be a compact non-algebraic surface of algebraic dimension $a(X)=1$. Since $a(x)=1$, there is a non-constant meromorphic function $h$ on X. If $h$ had indeterminacy points, we would have $D^2>0$.

However, if there were a meromorphic function $h$ on $X$, then the divisor $D=(h)$ would be principal and thus the first Chern class of the associated line bundle $L$ would vanish; i.e $c_1(L)=0$. Thus $D^2=(c_1(L)\cup c_1(L),[X])=0$. Thus, I  do not understand what is the meaning of this phrase. Can someone give me a hand?
